# Efficient assignment of lists to variables or to slices of variables

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

How can assignment of a list of elements be sped up? For scalar data, the answer would be to pre-assign an array:

```
import numpy as np
maxTime=1000; A=np.zeros(maxTime)
for t in range(maxTime): 
 data=get_fancy_data() 
 A[t]=data
```

However, if your `fancy_data` is a list that is a different size every timestep, then how can this be done efficiently?

```
python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; N=10**4; r=np.random.random(N); A=np.zeros(N);" \
"for i in range(N): A[:i+1] = r[:i+1]"
# 100 loops, best of 3: 14.9 msec per loop

python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; N=10**4; r=np.random.random(N); A=np.zeros(N);" \
"for i in range(N): A = r[:i+1]"
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.68 msec per loop
```

Not pre-allocating `A=np.zeros(N)` in the second example doesn't significantly alter the time taken.

I am not truly sure why the second example is faster. I suspect that `A[:i+1]` creates a copy of that part of A before assignment à la [Python list slicing efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435306/python-list-slicing-efficiency) .

I have some code with a bottleneck in such an operation, but could not find a faster approach to this.

*

I note that this is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice) because it concerns the meaning of `A[0:2]` - this is modifying the original array `A`, rather than creating a new array and discarding the old. However, this question concerns a way to modify an array `A` in a way that is *faster* than repeatedly making new arrays `A`.

Comment: You have no lists here. Lists and NumPy arrays may be superficially similar, but they have very different operation semantics and performance characteristics.

Comment: Well, for starters, the two examples are not doing the same thing. The first modifies the original *array*, the second never modifies the original array, instead, it reassigns slices of the original `A` to the name `A`, destining the original array for garbage collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How assignment works with python list slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice)

Comment: @user2357112 in this case, i don't think they do, in any meaningful way. In both cases, there is slicing as a view and slice assignment.

Comment: You can verify what @juanpa.arrivillaga is telling you by initting as `A=B=np.zeros(N)` and then looking at the contents of B after the loop completes. In the second case, you're not changing anything, just reassigning a reference over and over. Unsurprisingly, this is pretty quick, compared to moving data

Comment: @pvg: List slicing doesn't make a view. The (1-dimensional) slice assignment semantics are similar, but slice retrieval is entirely different.

Comment: @user2357112 'view' was a dumb choice of word. But the operational differences don't really matter here. The difference is that one of these does a lot more nothing than the other, just like it would if you were using lists. The list case would do slightly less nothing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, that's exactly my issue. My original code would repeatedly let `A=something` and thus repeatedly throw away the old array. I reasoned that doing this would mean I'm repeatedly allocating a little bit more memory, which would have the same issue as repeatedly doing `A=np.append(A,0)`, or `vector<int> x=0; x.push_back(0)`.

I expected that preallocation and assigning to slices of `A` would be faster. It was not. Thus, I wondered if there is a way to preallocate a large amount of memory in this way with better performance than reassigning A constantly.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you, my apologies. Using the word `list` was a slip of a mind. Indeed, these are arrays.

@pvg I think that I disagree that it's a duplicate. I know that `A[x:y]=B[:y-x]` modifies `A`, but it is surprisingly low performance and I was seeking a method that is higher performance than `A=B[y-x]` - if possible!

I would also disagree (partially) that `A=r[:i+1]` only moves a reference. If I subsequently modify `A` after this, `r` remains unchanged as long as `i+1!=len(r)`.
Thank you all for your comments thus far. They've been enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the mysteries of why my pure pythonic approach to attempting to preallocate was not faster, so I decided to go lower-level. I decided to use Cython, so I didn't have to work out how to pass numpy arrays to pure C code without copying them.

My solution is something like this:

**modify_array.pyx**

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t
@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
@cython.wraparound(False)  # turn off negative index wrapping for entire function

cpdef foo(unsigned int T, unsigned int S, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=2] A):
 cdef size_t t,s;
 for t in range(T): 
  for s in range(S): A[t,s]=data[t,S-s];
 return 0;
```

The array seems to be passed by reference, unless I am mistaken (since that concept does not exist in pure Python). In any case, any changes made to `foo` are reflected in the calling Python code. It's also possible to do this with numpy arrays:

**modify_array_np.pyx**

```
def baz(unsigned int T, unsigned int S, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=2] A):
 cdef size_t t,s;
 for t in range(T): 
  for s in range(S): A[t,s]=data[t,S-s]; 
   #n.b. Do not be tempted to try a more pythonic approach like A=data[:,::-1]:
   #it will require calls to the python interpreter and gut your speed boost.
return 0;
```

You should avoid using any numpy or python functions - that is, you should explicitly loop over indices instead of using np.sum, in order to ensure that the algorithm can be properly converted to C code.
`modify_array_np.pyx` is a factor of two faster than the equivalent solution I presented in the question. `modify_array.pyx` is a few tens of percentage faster again. It isn't as much as I hoped for, but it's better. If anyone has any faster suggestions, I'd be glad to hear them.

**Using the function in Python**

For reference, compile the above Cython code from the command line with,

`cython modify_array.pyx`

which produces a C file that you should then compile using your C compiler (see [here](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html) for required includes/flags). Then, in a python file:

```
import modify_array
import numpy as np
T=100; A=np.zeros((T,T))

for t in range(T):
 data=get_fancy_data()
 returnValue=modify_array.foo(t,data,A) #The function modifies A directly
 #Do more stuff
```